# How to make app quit after a few minutes on home screen?

Tags: ios, home-button

I'd like to ask a question what item on the plist could I use to make my app quit after a few minutes on the home screen.

I am already aware of the "Application does not run in background" boolean in the Plist, but this command completely quits the app when you press the home button if ticked YES. And completely runs the app forever until you turn the phone off when ticked NO.

I want my app to continue running in the background after a few minutes, and then quit by itself after maybe 30 minutes of user inactivity.

Some people almost never turn their Iphones off and it could be irritating to users if my game never quits and releases the memory.

I know of some games out there, like "cut the rope" that runs after you press the home screen. But quits by itself after maybe 1 hour of inactivity.

What coding option could I use to have the same quit-preference as "cut the rope"?

Comment: Do you talk about an ios app?

Comment: Set a NSTimer for 30 minutes, if it triggers before user interacts, close your app.